# Pairwise matrix multiplication with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have two MultiIndexed dataframes, each representing a set of k dxd matrices. I would like to compute the pairwise matrix products for each of the k pairs.

Does anyone know if this is possible in a single operation?

Here are sample dataframes (note that the values will be different, i.e. not the same in each matrix)

```
    ipdb> Lambda
                0         1
    0 0  1.274109 -0.753549
      1 -0.753549  1.230817
    1 0  1.274109 -0.753549
      1 -0.753549  1.230817
    2 0  1.274109 -0.753549
      1 -0.753549  1.230817
    3 0  1.274109 -0.753549
      1 -0.753549  1.230817

    ipdb> Sigma
          0   1
    0 0  10   0
      1   0  10
    1 0  10   0
      1   0  10
    2 0  10   0
      1   0  10
    3 0  10   0
      1   0  10

    ipdb> Lambda.ix[0].dot(Sigma.ix[0])
               0          1
    0  12.741094  -7.535495
    1  -7.535495  12.308169

    ipdb> Lambda.dot(Sigma)
    *** ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I am wondering how to correctly compose the last operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> Lambda.dot(Sigma.T)
            0                   1                   2                   3          
            0         1         0         1         0         1         0         1
0 0  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817
1 0  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817
2 0  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817
3 0  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817  -7.53549  12.30817
```

Comment: that's a whole $k^2$ number of matrix results, i.e. lambda_0 x sigma_0, lambda_0 x sigma_1, etc.  Is there a way (short of iterating) to get just the "diagonal" products, i.e. lambda_k x sigma_k ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what the OP had in mind, but often (like in my case), one is interested in just the `k` products (`Lambda.ix[k].dot(Sigma.ix[k]` for all `k`) and not the `k^2` ones (`Lambda.ix[i].dot(Sigma.ix[j]` for all combinations of `i, j`).

For those interested in the former, here is a version using `groupby` and `concat` (meh). It would be great to have a direct method, but there you go:

```
def drop_col_level(df, **kwds):
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(**kwds)
    return df

pd.concat([l.dot(drop_col_level(s.T, level=0))
           for (_, l), (_, s) in zip(Lambda.groupby(level=0), Sigma.groupby(level=0))])

Out[151]:
1           0         1
0 1                    
0 0  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817
1 0  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817
2 0  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817
3 0  12.74109  -7.53549
  1  -7.53549  12.30817
```